# Error 415 with Ajax request(Ajax, Spring)

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, spring-mvc

I send Ajax request to my server, but server doesn't get responce.

**PUT request:**

```
function editNavigation() {
        var flight={
            id:idAction.replace('edit',''),
            navigation:newNavigation
        };
        console.log(flight);
        var prefix = '/airline/';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: prefix +'flights/' + idAction.replace('edit',''),
            data: JSON.stringify(flight),
            headers:{contentType: "application/json"},
            success: function(receive) {
                $("#adminTable").empty();
                $("#informationP").replaceWith(receive);
                $("#hiddenLi").removeAttr('style');
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Error edited flight');
            }
        });
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = prefix + "/flights/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String updateFlight(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestBody FlightDto flightDto) {
        String returnText = "Flight edited successful";
        String str1 = flightDto.getNavigation();
        logger.info(str1);
        String str2 = id;
        logger.info(str2);
        return returnText;
    }
```

**Browser console:**

```
Object {id: "5", navigation: "sdf"}

PUT http://localhost:8080/airline/flights/5 415 ()
```

Why I get error 415? 
Why my controller doesn't send responce?

Comment: Have you tried to check what is the response from browser's network tab? Hit F12 button and check it, provide more information to us

Comment: Please verify the `Content-Type` header of the request that you send from network tab.

Comment: @Pete What Do you mean?

Comment: @BrunoDM, I provided full information:  *Object {id: "5", navigation: "sdf"}

PUT http://localhost:8080/airline/flights/5 415 ()*

Comment: This is the request, I wished to see the response

Comment: @BrunoDM no responce. There is request and this erorr *PUT http://localhost:8080/airline/flights/5 415 ()*  I thiink problem with controller

Comment: I want to know the value of `Content-Type` header of the request. we'll get HTTP 415 when the content type that sent by the is not supported by the server. Its clear that, your controller is restricted to consume only JSON. From the browser's network tab (within developer tools), check the headers send for this PUT request. Also have you tried sending this request with some rest clients(like Postman or ARC)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`415` resonance code is `Unsupported Media Type`.

1. If your service expect `POST`(or any kind) request and if user send
   `PUT` request then server will give this kind of response.
2. if user send wrong `MediaType` then also this type of error comes.

In your code, I think you have configure wrong `MediaType` which is `APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`. you can specify `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`.

I think this will helps.